# Why is <lightning-input-field> not setting value of checkboxes in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-recordeditform, lightning-inputfield, checkbox

I am getting data in my LWC from a wrapper class. In that data, I get object API name, field API name and value present in the field in the form of Strings. I iterate over the data from the wrapper class and take input from the user using `lightning-input-field`.

Code:

```html
<!-- iterate over wrapper list -->
<template iterator:item={wrapperListCopy}>
     <tr key={item.value.index}>
           <td>
                <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name={objectApiName}>
                     <lightning-input-field id={item.value.index} 
                                            field-name={item.value.inputFieldName} 
                                            value={item.value.filterValue}>
                     </lightning-input-field>
                </lightning-record-edit-form>
           </td>
     </tr>
</template>
```

The `filterValue` comes in String format. This code works for all fields except checkboxes. Even though `filterValue` contains `true` or `false`, the same is not reflected on checkbox in UI. By default, the checkbox appears checked on UI irrespective of the value present in `filterValue`.

It means that the checkbox is not getting value from the `value` attribute of `lightning-input-field`. Also, the checkbox always appears checked by default in UI. I want it to be unchecked by default. I am not able to understand why this is happening.

Is it because `filterValue` is a String? - I need it to be a string because all other fields are using it.

Or is it because I use `value` attribute instead of `checked` attribute? - I got an error saying that there is no such `checked` attribute.

Please help. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably due to JavaScript's type conversion rules; a string is converted to a Boolean in the following way:

- a string that is undefined, null or empty (i.e. "") becomes `false`
- a string that is none of the above becomes `true`

Thus, the strings "true" and "false" both become `true` as a Boolean. You need to change the way your filterValue is generated or used to resolve this. For example, ensure that filterValue is set to null for false and "true" otherwise.